# Установка windows на реальный жесткий диск через Virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Пришла идея установить windows на жесткий диск (физический) через Virtualbox (vmdk на основе жесткого диска делал через VBoxManage internalcommands), система установилась, в виртуалке отлично работает. Однако при перезагрузки машины и выбора Windows в grub, загручик винды возвращает ошибку 225, а система жалуется на отсутствие нужного оборудования. Как я понимаю, это происходит из-за того, что винда установилась на диск "Virtual Box Drive" (при установке она его видела таким), однако при загрузке этот диск уже сменил название, поэтому и ошибка. Вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь ее завести или же придется работать только в VirtualBox? Простую переустановку Windows через флешку прошу не предлагать, никак не получается ("ОС Windows несовместима с данным оборудованием компьютера", даже на образе от Microsoft такая проблема).
Оборудование (вывод dmidecode):

```html
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
63 structures occupying 2720 bytes.
Table at 0x000E0840.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
 Vendor: Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
 Version: P02AAG
 Release Date: 04/26/2012
 Address: 0xE0000
 Runtime Size: 128 kB
 ROM Size: 3072 kB
 Characteristics:
  PCI is supported
  BIOS is upgradeable
  BIOS shadowing is allowed
  Boot from CD is supported
  Selectable boot is supported
  EDD is supported
  Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
  8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
  Serial services are supported (int 14h)
  Printer services are supported (int 17h)
  CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
  NEC PC-98
  ACPI is supported
  USB legacy is supported
  BIOS boot specification is supported
  Function key-initiated network boot is supported
  Targeted content distribution is supported
  UEFI is supported
 BIOS Revision: 0.1

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
 Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
 Product Name: 700Z3C/700Z5C
 Version: 0.1
 Serial Number: HR4291DC700016
 UUID: B9204300-1DDA-11B2-8000-D82B83045D26
 Wake-up Type: Other
 SKU Number: System SKUNumber
 Family: ChiefRiver System

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
 Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
 Product Name: 700Z3C/700Z5C
 Version: FAB1
 Serial Number: 123490EN400015
 Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
 Features:
  Board is a hosting board
  Board is replaceable
 Location In Chassis: Part Component
 Chassis Handle: 0x0000
 Type: Motherboard
 Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
 Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
 Type: Laptop
 Lock: Not Present
 Version: 0.1
 Serial Number: 123490EN400015
 Asset Tag: Asset Tag
 Boot-up State: Safe
 Power Supply State: Safe
 Thermal State: Other
 Security Status: Other
 OEM Information: 0x00000000
 Height: Unspecified
 Number Of Power Cords: 1
 Contained Elements: 0
 SKU Number: Not Specified

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
 Socket Designation: CPU Socket - U3E1
 Type: Central Processor
 Family: Core i7
 Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
 ID: A9 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF
 Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 58, Stepping 9
 Flags:
  FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
  VME (Virtual mode extension)
  DE (Debugging extension)
  PSE (Page size extension)
  TSC (Time stamp counter)
  MSR (Model specific registers)
  PAE (Physical address extension)
  MCE (Machine check exception)
  CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
  APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
  SEP (Fast system call)
  MTRR (Memory type range registers)
  PGE (Page global enable)
  MCA (Machine check architecture)
  CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
  PAT (Page attribute table)
  PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
  CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
  DS (Debug store)
  ACPI (ACPI supported)
  MMX (MMX technology supported)
  FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
  SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
  SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
  SS (Self-snoop)
  HTT (Multi-threading)
  TM (Thermal monitor supported)
  PBE (Pending break enabled)
 Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
 Voltage: 0.8 V
 External Clock: 100 MHz
 Max Speed: 2300 MHz
 Current Speed: 2300 MHz
 Status: Populated, Enabled
 Upgrade: Socket rPGA988B
 L1 Cache Handle: 0x0002
 L2 Cache Handle: 0x0003
 L3 Cache Handle: 0x0004
 Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
 Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
 Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
 Core Count: 4
 Core Enabled: 4
 Thread Count: 8
 Characteristics:
  64-bit capable

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
 Socket Designation: L1-Cache
 Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
 Operational Mode: Write Through
 Location: Internal
 Installed Size: 32 kB
 Maximum Size: 32 kB
 Supported SRAM Types:
  Unknown
 Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
 Speed: Unknown
 Error Correction Type: Parity
 System Type: Data
 Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
 Socket Designation: L1-Cache
 Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
 Operational Mode: Write Through
 Location: Internal
 Installed Size: 32 kB
 Maximum Size: 32 kB
 Supported SRAM Types:
  Unknown
 Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
 Speed: Unknown
 Error Correction Type: Parity
 System Type: Instruction
 Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
 Socket Designation: L2-Cache
 Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
 Operational Mode: Write Through
 Location: Internal
 Installed Size: 256 kB
 Maximum Size: 256 kB
 Supported SRAM Types:
  Unknown
 Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
 Speed: Unknown
 Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
 System Type: Unified
 Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
 Socket Designation: L3-Cache
 Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
 Operational Mode: Write Back
 Location: Internal
 Installed Size: 6144 kB
 Maximum Size: 6144 kB
 Supported SRAM Types:
  Unknown
 Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
 Speed: Unknown
 Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
 System Type: Unified
 Associativity: 12-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: Keyboard
 External Connector Type: PS/2
 Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: Mouse
 External Connector Type: PS/2
 Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: Other
 External Reference Designator: COM 1
 External Connector Type: DB-9 male
 Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB3.0 - 1#/USB2.0 - 1#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB3.0 - 2#/USB2.0 - 2#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB3.0 - 3#/USB2.0 - 3#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB3.0 - 4#/USB2.0 - 4#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 5#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 6#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 7#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 8#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 9#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 10#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 11#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 12#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 13#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 14#
 External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
 Port Type: USB

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: Ethernet
 External Connector Type: RJ-45
 Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: SATA Port 1 J8J1
 Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
 External Reference Designator: None
 External Connector Type: None
 Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: SATA Port 2 J7G1
 Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
 External Reference Designator: None
 External Connector Type: None
 Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: SATA Port 3(ODD) J9E7
 Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
 External Reference Designator: None
 External Connector Type: None
 Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: eSATA Port 1 J6J1
 External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
 Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: eSATA Port 2 J7J1
 External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
 Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: None
 Internal Connector Type: None
 External Reference Designator: SATA Port 6(Docking)
 External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
 Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
 Designation: PEG Gen1/Gen2/Gen3 X16
 Type: x16 PCI Express
 Current Usage: In Use
 Length: Long
 ID: 0
 Characteristics:
  3.3 V is provided
  Opening is shared
  PME signal is supported
 Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
 Designation: PCI-Express 1 X1
 Type: x1 PCI Express
 Current Usage: In Use
 Length: Short
 ID: 1
 Characteristics:
  3.3 V is provided
  Opening is shared
  PME signal is supported
 Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
 Designation: PCI-Express 2 X1
 Type: x1 PCI Express
 Current Usage: Available
 Length: Short
 ID: 2
 Characteristics:
  3.3 V is provided
  Opening is shared
  PME signal is supported
 Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
 Designation: PCI-Express 3 X1
 Type: x1 PCI Express
 Current Usage: Available
 Length: Short
 ID: 3
 Characteristics:
  3.3 V is provided
  Opening is shared
  PME signal is supported
 Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
 Designation: PCI-Express 4 X1
 Type: x1 PCI Express
 Current Usage: In Use
 Length: Short
 ID: 4
 Characteristics:
  3.3 V is provided
  Opening is shared
  PME signal is supported
 Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
 Designation: PCI-Express 5 X4
 Type: x4 PCI Express
 Current Usage: Available
 Length: Short
 ID: 5
 Characteristics:
  3.3 V is provided
  Opening is shared
  PME signal is supported
 Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
 Type: Video
 Status: Enabled
 Description: Intel(R) Extreme Graphics 3 Controller

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
 Type: Sound
 Status: Enabled
 Description: Intel(R) Azalia Audio Device

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
 String 1: AAABAAAAAAAA 
 String 2: 2012/08/31
 String 3: SECPARTN:AAG

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
 Language Description Format: Abbreviated
 Installable Languages: 7
  en-US
  fr-FR
  ja-JP
  ko-KR
  zh-CHT
  zh-CHS
  ru-RU
 Currently Installed Language: en-US

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 22, 26 bytes
Portable Battery
 Location: Rear
 Manufacturer: Intel Corp.
 Manufacture Date: 2008
 Serial Number: 1.0
 Name: Smart Battery
 Design Capacity: Unknown
 Design Voltage: Unknown
 SBDS Version: V1.0
 Maximum Error: Unknown
 SBDS Chemistry: Lithium-Ion
 OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 32, 11 bytes
System Boot Information
 Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
 Type: OK
 Granularity: Unknown
 Operation: Unknown
 Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
 Memory Array Address: Unknown
 Device Address: Unknown
 Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 21, 7 bytes
Built-in Pointing Device
 Type: Mouse
 Interface: PS/2
 Buttons: 2

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 23, 13 bytes
System Reset
 Status: Disabled
 Watchdog Timer: Present
 Boot Option: Do Not Reboot
 Boot Option On Limit: Do Not Reboot
 Reset Count: Unknown
 Reset Limit: Unknown
 Timer Interval: Unknown
 Timeout: Unknown

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 24, 5 bytes
Hardware Security
 Power-On Password Status: Unknown
 Keyboard Password Status: Unknown
 Administrator Password Status: Unknown
 Front Panel Reset Status: Unknown

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 27, 14 bytes
Cooling Device
 Type: Unknown
 Status: Unknown
 OEM-specific Information: 0x00000090
 Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 39, 22 bytes
System Power Supply
 Location: TBD by ODM
 Name: TBD by ODM
 Manufacturer: TBD by ODM
 Serial Number: TBD by ODM
 Asset Tag: TBD by ODM
 Model Part Number: TBD by ODM
 Revision: 1.0
 Max Power Capacity: Unknown
 Status: Present, OK
 Type: Battery
 Input Voltage Range Switching: Other
 Plugged: Yes
 Hot Replaceable: Yes

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
 Location: System Board Or Motherboard
 Use: System Memory
 Error Correction Type: None
 Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
 Error Information Handle: Not Provided
 Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0034
 Error Information Handle: Not Provided
 Total Width: 64 bits
 Data Width: 64 bits
 Size: 4096 MB
 Form Factor: SODIMM
 Set: None
 Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
 Bank Locator: BANK 0
 Type: DDR3
 Type Detail: Synchronous
 Speed: 1333 MHz
 Manufacturer: Samsung
 Serial Number: 00000000
 Asset Tag: 9876543210
 Part Number: M471B5273DH0-CK0  
 Rank: Unknown
 Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0034
 Error Information Handle: Not Provided
 Total Width: Unknown
 Data Width: Unknown
 Size: No Module Installed
 Form Factor: DIMM
 Set: None
 Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
 Bank Locator: BANK 1
 Type: Unknown
 Type Detail: None
 Speed: Unknown
 Manufacturer: Not Specified
 Serial Number: Not Specified
 Asset Tag: 9876543210
 Part Number: Not Specified
 Rank: Unknown
 Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0034
 Error Information Handle: Not Provided
 Total Width: 64 bits
 Data Width: 64 bits
 Size: 8192 MB
 Form Factor: SODIMM
 Set: None
 Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
 Bank Locator: BANK 2
 Type: DDR3
 Type Detail: Synchronous
 Speed: 1333 MHz
 Manufacturer: 029E
 Serial Number: 00000000
 Asset Tag: 9876543210
 Part Number: CMSX8GX3M1A1600C10
 Rank: Unknown
 Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0034
 Error Information Handle: Not Provided
 Total Width: Unknown
 Data Width: Unknown
 Size: No Module Installed
 Form Factor: DIMM
 Set: None
 Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
 Bank Locator: BANK 3
 Type: Unknown
 Type Detail: None
 Speed: Unknown
 Manufacturer: Not Specified
 Serial Number: Not Specified
 Asset Tag: 9876543210
 Part Number: Not Specified
 Rank: Unknown
 Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
 Starting Address: 0x00000000000
 Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
 Range Size: 8 GB
 Physical Device Handle: 0x0035
 Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x003C
 Partition Row Position: 1
 Interleave Position: 1
 Interleaved Data Depth: 2

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
 Starting Address: 0x00000000000
 Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
 Range Size: 8 GB
 Physical Device Handle: 0x0036
 Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x003C
 Partition Row Position: 1
 Interleave Position: 2
 Interleaved Data Depth: 2

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
 Starting Address: 0x00200000000
 Ending Address: 0x002FFFFFFFF
 Range Size: 4 GB
 Physical Device Handle: 0x0037
 Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x003C
 Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
 Starting Address: 0x00000000000
 Ending Address: 0x002FFFFFFFF
 Range Size: 12 GB
 Physical Array Handle: 0x0034
 Partition Width: 4

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 15, 81 bytes
System Event Log
 Area Length: 34 bytes
 Header Start Offset: 0x0000
 Header Length: 16 bytes
 Data Start Offset: 0x0010
 Access Method: General-purpose non-volatile data functions
 Access Address: 0x00F0
 Status: Valid, Not Full
 Change Token: 0x00000001
 Header Format: Type 1
 Supported Log Type Descriptors: 29
 Descriptor 1: Single-bit ECC memory error
 Data Format 1: Multiple-event handle
 Descriptor 2: Multi-bit ECC memory error
 Data Format 2: Multiple-event handle
 Descriptor 3: Parity memory error
 Data Format 3: None
 Descriptor 4: Bus timeout
 Data Format 4: None
 Descriptor 5: I/O channel block
 Data Format 5: None
 Descriptor 6: Software NMI
 Data Format 6: None
 Descriptor 7: POST memory resize
 Data Format 7: None
 Descriptor 8: POST error
 Data Format 8: POST results bitmap
 Descriptor 9: PCI parity error
 Data Format 9: None
 Descriptor 10: PCI system error
 Data Format 10: None
 Descriptor 11: CPU failure
 Data Format 11: None
 Descriptor 12: EISA failsafe timer timeout
 Data Format 12: None
 Descriptor 13: Correctable memory log disabled
 Data Format 13: None
 Descriptor 14: Logging disabled
 Data Format 14: None
 Descriptor 15: System limit exceeded
 Data Format 15: None
 Descriptor 16: Asynchronous hardware timer expired
 Data Format 16: None
 Descriptor 17: System configuration information
 Data Format 17: None
 Descriptor 18: Hard disk information
 Data Format 18: None
 Descriptor 19: System reconfigured
 Data Format 19: None
 Descriptor 20: Uncorrectable CPU-complex error
 Data Format 20: None
 Descriptor 21: Log area reset/cleared
 Data Format 21: None
 Descriptor 22: System boot
 Data Format 22: None
 Descriptor 23: OEM-specific
 Data Format 23: None
 Descriptor 24: OEM-specific
 Data Format 24: None
 Descriptor 25: OEM-specific
 Data Format 25: None
 Descriptor 26: OEM-specific
 Data Format 26: None
 Descriptor 27: OEM-specific
 Data Format 27: None
 Descriptor 28: OEM-specific
 Data Format 28: None
 Descriptor 29: OEM-specific
 Data Format 29: None

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: А что за железо такое? И какой виндуз ставил?

Comment: http://forum.oszone.net/post-2315395.html - эту ветку реестра правил? Снеси дрова на контроллер с того какой есть на старндартный.

Comment: Жесткий диск: SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series. Ставил Windows 7. Ветку реестра правил, но не помогло, драйвера стоят от Microsoft (шли из коробки вместе с виндой).

Comment: На сам винт наплевать. Остальное железо какое, что на него не влазит 7?

Comment: @donRumata вывод dmidecode прикрепил к описанию вопроса

Comment: Ввы ставили винду под одну материнку и вообще систему в целом, а она при запуске теперь видит совсем другую, это не очень удивительно. Попробуйте поставить дрова под реальное оборудование.

Comment: Оно http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/model/NP700Z5C-S01HK ? Там в биос можно войти? Если да, то там есть что-нить со словами `uefi disable`, `csm support enable`, `secure boot disable` или типа того?

Comment: @donRumata UEFI уже отключен, в ходе установки убунты еще отключил (иначе ноут окирпичится, баг Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557)